# Add a default view on a navigation view controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a navigation controller and a tab bar where I have buttons for multiple options. When a button is ever pressed it pushes its respective viewcontroller in navigation controller. That's fine, but when I again press the button in tab bar after loading any other suboption viewcontroller in navigation controller, it shows blank screen instead of that "options screen" which it shows when I touch it first time.

I am using this code:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:accountOptions animated:NO];
```

Comment: try to explore uinavigationcontrollerdelegate protocol reference, http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: can u add more details of the coding part like where did u add the tabbar is it in the app delegate file of some what like that

Answer (score 0):

You're pushing same view controller twice without ever poping it from navigation controller.

You can either pop view controller when switching to another one or push view controllers once on navigation controller in tab bar and be done with it.